# Laptop Ubuntu 21.04 brightness can't be adjusted

Tags: nvidia, graphics, brightness, backlight, amdgpu

I received my new laptop with Ubuntu 21.04 on it, Nvidia 3070 GPU and Ryzen 9 5000 series CPU (with internal GPU). Running kernel 5.11.0-25-generic. Gnome tries to render most things using the Ryzen GPU.

For some reason i am unable to change the brightness of the laptop screen. I do see the following backlight device `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/` which changes to `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/` when i use the bios to use the discrete GPU. Using the discrete GPU does make the brightness up/down work. which leads me to believe im missing drivers? The file `brightness` in the `sys` dir does change values when adjusting the brightness.

I tried:

- Grub setting changes
- adding "brightness_control" option to xorg settings for AMDGPU

How do i go about trying to fix this? i want to use hybrid mode so i dont use up my battery in no-time.

edit:

It's a Skikk Laptop, 15MD7Y. So not a well known brand or anything.

- AMD® Ryzen 9 5900hx with radeon graphics × 16  NVIDIA Corporation
- GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q]

Comment: Could you update your question to include the brand and model of notebook? Some machines need a different combination of steps to have the backlight adjustment done.

Comment: @matigo I added it to the question.